# Laravel joins the best way

Tags: laravel-4

Wondered if someone would help me acheive this post I made on laravel forums

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=65062#p65062

Question:

I am getting the following error from my controller:

`syntax error, unexpected '$address' (T_VARIABLE)`
Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $accounts = Accounts::find($id);
    $address  = Accounts::find($id)->address;
    return View::make('reports.edit',compact('user', $user, 'accounts', $accounts, 'address' $address))
        ->with('title', 'Edit Account');
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot just link to a forum with your question. You should explain the issue, display your code and describe the problems you are encountering on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
compact('user', $user, 'accounts', $accounts, 'address' $address)
```

You have no comma, the [`compact`](https://www.php.net/compact) function should just be used like this:

```
compact('user', 'accounts' 'address')
```

A quote from the documentation explains it very clearly:

> For each of these, compact() looks for a variable with that name in
> the current symbol table and adds it to the output array such that the
> variable name becomes the key and the contents of the variable become
> the value for that key. In short, it does the opposite of extract().

So having `$user` within the function is useless as it will be trying to look for a variable with the value of `$user`.

Comment: bloodyhell, yes how did i miss that! Thanks dude

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II Mark it as accepted please, otherwise this question will show up unanswered for no reason.